# How to insert POST data

Tags: php, mongodb

I do not know how to insert POST data to `mongodb` collection. I try to do it like this:

```
$collection ->insert($_POST);
```

But in this case I get `An Internal Server Error`. What is the best and most concise way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to make an array of all post data and pass it to insert like

```
<?php
  $post = array("username" =>$_POST['username'], "password" => $_POST['password']);
  $collection->insert($post);
?>
```